# Синтаксис cmake: как линковать сторонние библиотеки

Tags: c++, cmake, сборка

Добрый вечер, друзья! Такая проблема.
Хочу прилинковать библиотеки `GLEW` и `GLUT` в проект с помощью cmake, но не пойму как это делать, потому как только начал разбираться с данной системой сборки.

ОС: Linux

Подскажите пожалуйста.
Пути к библиотекам:

```
GLEW:
lib: /usr/lib64/
include: /usr/include/GL/
GLUT:
lib: /usr/local/lib/
include: /usr/local/include/GL/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Должно быть как-то так:

```
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)
include_directories( ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS}  ${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

target_link_libraries( project_name ${GLEW_LIBRARIES} ${GLUT_LIBRARY} )
```

Ссылка на небольшие уроки, в содержании которыз Вы найдете интересующую Вас информацию - [линк](https://habrahabr.ru/post/155467/), [линк](http://procplusplus.blogspot.ru/search/label/cmake)

`find_package` - ищем расширение CMake; употреблено с `REQUIRED` - это значит, что в случае неудачного поиска сборка прервется.

`target_link_libraries` - перечисляем инструкции, которые необходимо добавить в сборочный файл для подключения к проекту сторонних библиотек.

*Что-то пошло не так ? Идете на cmake.org, ищете нужные расширения, смотрите, какие макросы там определены для конкретного расширения, если что-то поменялось - меняете, пробуете.. - не работает? - возвращаетесь - разбираемся.*